# ListView not always displaying values

Tags: android, listview, double, listview-adapter

**ListView sometimes displays values and sometimes doesn't**
I'm trying to make an app that uses the Bissection method to find an approximate root of a function. App makes calculation and displays the results in a listView, it works fine for the most time but after some testing I found out that some functions' results are not shown.

E.g. x^3-9x+3 from 1 to 3 works but from 0 to 1 doesn't.

img https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvEzz.png

- Tried debugging and both inputs go thru the same lines of code, everything seems fine. Nothing shows in Logcat.
- ListView is working because for some inputs it displays values
- ArrayAdapter works too for the same reason of listView, also because both arrays in the example had similar double values.It shouldn't be a problem

What am i missing?

Code:

`setListAdapter(new BisseccaoAdapter(a_array, b_array,
                            c_array, fc_array));`

```
class BisseccaoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    double[] a2, b2, c2, fc2;


    BisseccaoAdapter() {
        a2 = null;
        b2 = null;
        c2 = null;
        fc2 = null;
    }

    public BisseccaoAdapter(double[] a_array, double[] b_array,
            double[] c_array, double[] fc_array) {

        a2 = a_array;
        b2 = b_array;
        c2 = c_array;
        fc2 = fc_array;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){

            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha_listview, parent, false);

            // set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.i = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lista_i);
            viewHolder.at = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lista_a);
            viewHolder.bt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lista_b);
            viewHolder.ct = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lista_c);
            viewHolder.fct = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lista_fc);

            // store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{

            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // assign values if the object is not null
        if(a2.length != 0) {
            // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
            viewHolder.i.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));
            viewHolder.at.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.#######").format(a2[position]));
            viewHolder.bt.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.#######").format(b2[position]));
            viewHolder.ct.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.########").format(c2[position]));
            viewHolder.fct.setText(new DecimalFormat(".#######E0").format(fc2[position]));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        for (i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
            if (a2[i] == 0) {
                break;
            }

        }

        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without code we can't know what is happening.

Comment: in case of 0 to 1, have does your list of results gets created? Also post the code where you are processing the f(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In getCount() you need to return the count of the array. check in case of 0 to 1, whether a2[i] ==0, If it is then i would be returned as a count, whereas you need to return a2.length here. getCount() results in invocation of getView() which is then responsible for rendering the view on screen.

For instance, in case of 0 to 1, a2[0] == 0, then i = 0, will be returned, so framework will get to know that there is nothing to display since count is 0.

> So you should return a2.length.

It would be even better that you bundle all these arrays in a class and use a arraylist of instances of class and return the size of the list in `getCount()`.

Comment: AAh a2[0] was 0! Thats it! Thanks a lot!